# Sharepoint Workflow: Where to store configuration settings?

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, workflow, settings

I am currently writing a Sharepoint Workflow that is activated when a user saves an Excel file to a Library. Now I need to process this file and store certain information to a certain list.
Whats the best way to store configuration settings like the name of the output list, names of the Excel columns that the Workflow needs to process, etc?

I understand that there seem to be a lot of different possible solutions like web config, Properties, etc. But since I am totally new to Sharepoint, I cannot properly assess these methods. Which one is the easiest for me to use?

Thank you.

Edit: A Visual Studio Workflow, written in C#

Comment: SharePoint Designer Workflow, Visual Studio Workflow, Nintex workflow or other?

Comment: It's a Visual Studio Workflow, written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article is a good starting point [Six Ways to to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx) but personally I would be following the [MSDN SharePoint Guidance Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649628.aspx) which uses the Property Bag storage for their implementation of a hierarchical Configuration Manager which allows you to do things like a farm wide setting but overridden for certain site collections/sites/lists etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan. That's extremely valuable!